# For Loop over Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, coffeescript, backbone.js-collections

Fairly new to backbone, so this is a really basic question. I have a Backbone collection passed into a function and I can prove that it has been passed and that the models in the collection have ids.

Here's how I'm setting the ids -

```
convertToMapObjects: (results)  =>
   objectList = new ObjectList()
   results.each(result)->
    testObj = new TestObject()
    testObj.set
      id = result.get("id")
    objectList.add(testObj)
```

And in another function ( accessed through making the model trigger an event) -

```
getIds: (objects) =>
ids = (object.id for object in objects)
```

I think the issue may be because of how I'm iterating through the collection because when I tried doing

```
for object in objects
   console.log(object)
```

I saw two undefineds. Is this correct? If so, why can't I use a for loop to go through a backbone collection? Also, is there a way I could do so?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A Backbone collection is not an array so `for ... in` won't produce the results you're expecting. You want to look at the collection's [`models`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models) property if you want to use a simple loop.

However, Backbone collections have [various Underscore methods mixed in](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods):

> **Underscore Methods (28)**
>
> Backbone proxies to Underscore.js to provide 28 iteration functions on **Backbone.Collection**. They aren't all documented here, but you can take a look at the Underscore documentation for the full details…
>
> - forEach (each)
> - ...

So you can use [`map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) or [`pluck`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-pluck) if you'd like to avoid accessing the [`models` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models):

```
ids = objects.map (m) -> m.id
ids = objects.pluck 'id'
```

The `pluck` method is, more or less, just a special case of `map` but collections implement a native version rather than using the Underscore version so that they can pluck model attributes rather than simple object properties.

Answer (score 5):

You want to loop over the [`models` property](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-models) of the collection, not the collection object itself.

Answer (score 4):

```
for object in object.models
```

This will give you a model in the collection