# collection.each() does not iterate over models

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to iterate over models fetched by collection.

I have folowing piece of code:

```
initialize: function() {
                this.collection = new UserCollection();
                this.collection.fetch();
                this.render();
            },

            renderCollection: function() {
                console.log("rendering collection");
                this.collection.each(function(index,model){
                    console.log("model"); 
                });
                console.log(this.collection);
            },

render: function() {
                this.template = _.template(template, {});
                this.$el.html(this.template);
                // some other stuff
                this.renderCollection();
}
```

and results:

```
rendering collection

d {models: Array[0], length: 0, _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
_byId: Object
_idAttr: "id"
length: 4
models: Array[4]
0: d
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
created: "2013-02-13 09:22:42"
id: "1"
modified: "2013-02-13 09:22:42"
role: "admin"
username: "email@gmail.com"
__proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c5"
collection: d
id: "1"
__proto__: e
1: d
2: d
3: d
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: e
 user_list.js:25
```

So the fetch method did work - in object dump I can find 4 records fetched but iterating over the collection does not work...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the output you provided, it doesn't look like any "model" has been printed. It's probably caused by, when the `.each()` block is executed, `this.collection` may not have been completely fetched yet. This is due to the async nature of JavaScript.

Try this in your initialize method:

```
initialize: function() {
    var me = this;
    this.collection = new UserCollection();
    // Listen to 'reset' events from collection, so when .fetch() is completed and all
    // ready to go, it'll trigger .render() automatically.
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    this.collection.fetch();
},
```

The other way to handle this is to add a success handler on fetch, but I think listening to reset events should be sufficient in this case.

Hope this helps!

BTW, like Cyclone says, the handler for .each should just be a model without the index. :)

Comment: the issue could come as well from the server output that needs to be a valid array of json objects. i.e in php an indexed json_encoded array

Comment: Your iterator should either be:

'this.collection.each(function(model){...});'

OR

'this.collection.each(function(model,index){...});'

OP has index and model the wrong way around.

Comment: I had to do an each over collection.models like this (not collection): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726943/for-loop-over-backbone-collection...this was my problem.

Answer (score 20):

Doing `each` on collection gives `model` itself as an `argument`.

Try this:

```
this.collection.each(function(model){
  console.log(model); 
});
```

It should give you the `model` for the current iteration.